# Yii2 security : $app->security->decryptByPassword returns false

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I am new in yii2, in my app i receive username and password of another system from users.
But i do not want store their password as plain text.
So i decided to encrypt passwords before storing.

**Update**

My view:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if($model->uid !== Yii::$app->user->identity->id)
        return $this->redirect('index');

    $model->instapass = Yii::$app->security->decryptByPassword($model->instapass, 'somekey');

    var_dump($model->instapass);

    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

My update :

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if( $model->uid !== Yii::$app->user->identity->id)
        return $this->redirect('index');

    $result = $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());

    if(!$result || !$model->validate()) {
        $model->instapass = Yii::$app->security->decryptByPassword($model->instapass, 'somekey');

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }

    $model->instapass = Yii::$app->security->encryptByPassword($model->instapass, 'somekey');

    if ($model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Edited codes to make it more clear how i validate the values.

I can not hash the passwords, because my script must be able to decrypt the passwords when they are needed.

The update code works fine, but in the view `decryptByPassword` method always returns false.
Anyone can help me find where is the problem ?

Thanks.

**Update**

When i enter 123 in Update page `encryptbypassword` generates sth like this (stored in database):

```
+?????OrS?-05ff75d8f4d6531f9bf1d6cab3fdecddd72fc541e3846f12d96e383286f122f1??%*?B0e
```

As you can see some characters are not readable. Maybe this is the problem.

**Update (Problem resolved)**

I found after printing or storing encrypted strings they become broken, then i used base64_encode before storing the string and base64_decode before sending the string to decrypt method, and it works now. I do not know if using base64_encode decode is correct way or not but it works now !
If anyone know a better way please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: You are not validating `$model->instapass` before trying to save it. Are you 100% sure this is encrypted successfully? I must add that storing passwords like that is not secure.

Comment: I looked at phpmyadmin and everything was ok. Also my model validates the inputs. I used var_dump to make sure $model->instapass is not empty before encryption and it was ok.

Comment: Oh, if you placed call to `validate()` somewhere else it's ok then. Without this info it looks like validation is called in only in `save()` so `instapass` can be passed empty or something like that. Anyway, make sure you are not encrypting this value twice - there is the same attribute used for pre and postencrypted value so it might happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add hashed passwords in yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490219/how-to-add-hashed-passwords-in-yii2)

Comment: @Bizley Thanks for your recomendations, I edited codes and now im sure that encryption does not happens twice. But that method still returns false. Yasar Arafath This is not duplicate because i know what i want do. But the method decryptByPassword always returns false. Is there any specific rules for the password parameter on this method ?