# How to hash a password correctly in Yii2 (Getting "Hash is invalid" error)

Tags: php, hash, yii2

I am currently experimenting with Yii2 and I am trying to hash the Password of a newly created user. The I think the hashing gets done well, but when I try to login with the user and his newly hashed password I get the `Hash is invalid` Error for some reason.

I have checked [how to add hashed passwords in yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29490219/how-to-add-hashed-passwords-in-yii2) but I can't find a solution working for me.

In my `UserController.php`i have the following action:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new User();

        if ($this->request->isPost) {
            if ($model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
                \Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);
                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->iduser]);
            }
        } else {
            $model->loadDefaultValues();
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

And in my `User.php` model I use the following function to validate the password:

```
public function validatePassword($password) {
        if(is_null($this->password)) {
            return false;
        }
        return Yii::$app->getSecurity()->validatePassword($password, $this->password);
    }
```

Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong? Because I can't see what I am missing here.

Comment: You call `generatePasswordHash()` but you don't do anything with the hash returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saving unhashed password with `$model->save()`.
The `\Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password)` creates password hash and returns it. But you are not using returned hash in any way.

You need to load data into model, set the hashed password in `password` attribute of model and then save the model:

```php
if ($this->request->isPost) {
    if ($model->load($this->request->post())) {
        $model->password = \Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);
        if ($model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->iduser]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can also override `load()` method to hash password right after data are loaded.

```
class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public function load($data, $formName = null)
    {
        $result = parent::load($data, $formName);

        //only hash password if it was changed
        if ($result && $this->isAttributeChanged('password')) {
            $this->password = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    // ... other definitions ...
}
```

Comment: This is really good and works fine so far. The only thing that I don't get is the `load($data, $formName)` function. Care to explain?

Comment: Do you mean that `$result = parent::load($data, $formName);` line? That's there to call original implementation of `load()` method to load data into model. Then, if the load was successful the extra work is done and result of original `load()` is returned.

Comment: I think I get it. I have to thank you once again.